# How to escape all special characters in Scala

Tags: scala

If I have a JSON string:

```
{"location":"Irvine","role":"Owsla","resident":{"years":15,"deposit":true},"car":"BMW","multiple-residents":{"number":4,"name":"Fiver","role":{"employer":"ResortShare","computer":{"make":"mac","model":"air"},"comapny-car":false},"age":4,"position":"Fiver"},"age":"6","name1":"Bob","nick-name":"Bigwig"}
```

How can I assign it to a `val s:String` ?

Comment: You can use triple quotes, like `val s = """a long string with "quotes" ..."""`.

Comment: @ Peter, thanks. Yet again. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to put it in a string literal (triple quotes allow using quotes inside the string literal without escaping):

```
val s = """{"location":"Irvine","role":"Owsla","resident":{"years":15,"deposit":true},"car":"BMW","multiple-residents":{"number":4,"name":"Fiver","role":{"employer":"ResortShare","computer":{"make":"mac","model":"air"},"comapny-car":false},"age":4,"position":"Fiver"},"age":"6","name1":"Bob","nick-name":"Bigwig"}"""
```

Another way is to [read it from a resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar), which may or may not be considered cleaner:

```
import scala.io.Source
val s = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/data.json"), "UTF-8").mkString
```

Comment: @ rightfold, I'll probably end up using both methods, but for testing I'll use the triple ' " ' .  Thank you very much, it's just what I needed.